# Convert large spark DF to pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have a huge (1258355, 14) pyspark dataframe that has to be converted to pandas df. Probably there is a memory issue (modifying the config file did not work)
`pdf = df.toPandas()` fails. `pdf1 = df.limit(1000)` works. How can I iterate through the whole df, convert the slices to pandas df and join these at last?

Comment: Why do you want to convert your `pyspark` dataframe to `pandas` equivalent, is there a specific use case? There would be serious memory implications as `pandas` brings entire data to the driver side! Having said that, as the data grows it is highly likely that your cluster would face `OOM` (Out of Memory) errors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: code for pandas analysis is already written and working for a similar size dataset. I want to run it for this dataset as well, I just have to convert to pandas

Comment: You might want to try [`pandas_udf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf) instead of converting the whole dataset to Pandas